# WP All Export ACF image url

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wpallimport

In my posts i have ACF field image (array). I can't understand how export image url in xml file by function editor. Help me please

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyWV7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

From plugin documentation:

> ACF fields are automatically detected by WP All Export. To customize
> your export file, select fields from Available Data > ACF and drag and
> drop them into the export editor.
>
> Image fields export the URL to the image or file. Multiple images or
> files in a single field will be separated by the pipe ( | ) character.

https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/export-acf-media-fields-to-csv-or-xml/

In other words, looks like you don't have to do anything special - just drag and drop as per the screenshot on the documentation page.